# Upgrade node for npm at Visual Studio Team Services

Tags: node.js, azure-devops

I have a build using Visual Studio Team Services (visual studio online) that fails on the the npm step.  The problem is that it uses an old version of node.js that does not support what I need.  It's using 0.12.7 which is pretty old - I use 6 in my local visual studio instance.

How do I upgrade the version of node that this uses?

Comment: I know it's something we're currently looking into at the moment...

Answer (score 1):

You have no control over the hosted build agent. If you're using the hosted agent and need software that's not available, you'll have to set up your own agent that you control.

You can do this very easily in Azure.